# Logging to a Custom log file or dynamic log time stamp in Magento2

Tags: magento2, logging, psr-logger

How i can create my own custom log file with time stamp each time when i log the error

Answer (score 3):

create Your own Handler

```
    <?php
    namespace Alshaya\Vistorinfo\Model;

    use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface;
    use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
    use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
    use Monolog\Logger;

    class Handler extends \Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base
    {
        /**
         * Logging level
         * @var int
         */
        protected $loggerType = Logger::INFO;

        /**
         * File name
         * @var string
         */
        public $fileName = '';
        /**
         * File name
         * @var string
         */
        public $cutomfileName = 'NO_PATH';
        /**
         * @var TimezoneInterface
         */
        protected $_localeDate;

        public function __construct(
            DriverInterface $filesystem,
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $corefilesystem,
            \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
            $filePath = null
        ) {
            $this->_localeDate = $localeDate;
            $corefilesystem= $corefilesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR); 
            $logpath = $corefilesystem->getAbsolutePath('log/');


            // Custom log file name for each day because log will be full for optimization 
            $filename = 'vistorInfo_'.Date('Y_m_d').'.log';

            $filepath = $logpath . $filename;
            $this->cutomfileName=$filepath;
            parent::__construct(
                $filesystem,
                $filepath
            );
   //custom message format 
           $this->setFormatter(new LineFormatter('%message%'.PHP_EOL,null,true));

        }
    }
```

call this handler in any class

```
public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Alshaya\Vistorinfo\Model\Handler $handler,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress $ip,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->handler = $handler;
        $this->ip = $ip;
        // Custom log file name for each day because log will be full for optimization 
        $this->logger->setHandlers ( [$this->handler] );
    }
```

and call

```
$this->logger->info( "hello world" );
```

Answer (score 1):

first create your own handler

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class Handler extends \Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base
{
    /**
     * Logging level
     * @var int
     */
    protected $loggerType = Logger::INFO;

    /**
     * File name
     * @var string
     */
    public $fileName = '';
    /**
     * File name
     * @var string
     */
    public $cutomfileName = 'NO_PATH';
    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $_localeDate;

    public function __construct(
        DriverInterface $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $corefilesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        $filePath = null
    ) {
        $this->_localeDate = $localeDate;
        $corefilesystem= $corefilesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR); 
        $logpath = $corefilesystem->getAbsolutePath('log/');

        $filename = 'delivery_martix/import_'. $this->getTimeStamp() .'.log';
        $filepath = $logpath . $filename;
        $this->cutomfileName=$filepath;
        parent::__construct(
            $filesystem,
            $filepath
        );
    }

    public function getCustomFile()
    {
        return  $this->cutomfileName;
    }
    public function getTimeStamp()
    {
        return $this->_localeDate->formatDateTime($this->_localeDate->date(),
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        'Y_M_d_H_mm_ss'
        );
    }
}
```

and in your main file

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Import;

class Save
{   
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_handler;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \YourNamespace\YourModule\Model\Handler $handler,

    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_handler = $handler;

    }



     public function execute()
    {

            $this->messageManager->addError(
                                __('Few Items are not inserted, Please check log.'. $this->_handler->getCustomFile())
                            );
            $this->_logger->critical('Duplicate Entry Not Allowed, this  Combination already exists',$data);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also log in below way  specially you need log with log file AS like order increment id

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, // based on class thi will change
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    ){
       $this->_logDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


   public function execute()
{
    $logpath = $this->_logDirectory->getAbsolutePath('log/orders/');    
    if(!$this->_logDirectory->isExist($this->_logDirectory->getRelativePath('log/orders/'))){
         //if the folder not exit it will create one dummy file 
        $jsonpath =  $this->_logDirectory->getRelativePath('log/orders/');
        $filePath = $jsonpath.'test'.'.log';
        $this->_logDirectory->writeFile($filePath, 'test file created');
    }                   

    $filename = 'import_.'$order->getIncrementId()'.log';
    $filepath = $logpath . $filename;

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream($filepath);
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $msg='rrr';
    $logger->info($msg);
    $logger->info(print_r($order->getData(),1)); 

}
```